# How to map right windows key to backspace?

Tags: keyboard

BackSpace key is out of range of my right hand, and everytime I work with text editor in such conditions where I need a backspace key stroke, it makes me look at my keyboard, and so disturbs my rhythm of typing.

I hardly use my Right *Windows* key. I want to map it to perform as backspace key.

<sub>*(I have a US standard layout keyboard.)*</sub>

Comment: Do you mean the context menu key?

Comment: @vasa1 no! The **right *windows* key** which is the key left to context menu key.

Comment: Okay! I don't have that key on my lappie.